# Read a custom formatted datetime with numpy

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I'm trying to load time series data from some files.  The data has this format

```
04/02/2015 19:07:53.951,3195,1751,-44,-25
```

I'm using this code to load the whole file as a numpy object.

```
 content = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype={'names': ('timestamp', 'tick', 'ch', 'NodeI', 'Base'),
                                      'formats': ('datetime64[us]', 'i4', 'i4', 'i4', 'i4')}, delimiter=',', skiprows=27)
```

but i got an error with the datetime format

```
ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "04/02/2015 19:07:53.951" at position 2
```

there is an easy way to define the datetime format I'm reading? There files with a lot of data so I'm trying not to walk the file more than once.

Comment: My suggesion: Read the timestamp in a string data type and do the conversion afterwards for each entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `converters` argument in order to apply a converter function to the data on the first column:

```
import datetime

def parsetime(v): 
    return np.datetime64(
        datetime.datetime.strptime(v, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
    )

content = np.loadtxt(
    filename, 
    dtype={
        'names': ('timestamp', 'tick', 'ch', 'NodeI', 'Base'),
        'formats': ('datetime64[us]', 'i4', 'i4', 'i4', 'i4')
    }, 
    delimiter=',', 
    skiprows=27,
    converters={0: parsetime},
)
```

I assume your data file is using `D/M/Y`, adjust the format string accordingly if you are using `M/D/Y`.

Comment: I realize the data saved this way is an array, but every row is a "void" type,  instead of ndarray, so I cant do  data [:,2]  for example to obtain a whole column

Comment: Is that the syntax to get all values from the 3rd column? In order to get the whole column, for example, the 3 column (index 2) I would do `content['ch']`... Sorry, I'm a web developer, not a data scientist, I don't really use numpy.

Comment: good point it could work that way (the other way works with the panda solution),  so I'll test the efficiency of both

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the pandas library and [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), you can use `parse_dates` to select the column and set `infer_datetime_format` to convert it to datetime format:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.read_csv('nu.txt',parse_dates=[0],infer_datetime_format=True,sep=',',header=None)

a.iloc[:,0]



0   2015-04-02 19:07:53.951
1   2015-04-02 19:07:53.951
2   2015-04-02 19:07:53.951
3   2015-04-02 19:07:53.951
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
# assumes file with four identical rows and no header
```

Also, it's easy to convert to numpy, if needed:

```
b=np.array(a)
array([[Timestamp('2015-04-02 19:07:53.951000'), 3195L, 1751L, -44L, -25L],
       [Timestamp('2015-04-02 19:07:53.951000'), 3195L, 1751L, -44L, -25L],
       [Timestamp('2015-04-02 19:07:53.951000'), 3195L, 1751L, -44L, -25L],
       [Timestamp('2015-04-02 19:07:53.951000'), 3195L, 1751L, -44L, -25L]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: it works pretty well even if it feels quite slow. I'll do some more test. Thanks anyway,.

Comment: Doesn't `pd.read_csv` create Pandas datetime objects which have `ns` resolution? What if I want dates spanning to `9999-12-31`?